# Hashbang, prereder.io and the robots

Tags: angularjs, googlebot, hashbang, prerender

I am a little confused about how the search bots are going to crawl my ajax site.

http://www.example.com contains 3 links

- #!/abc
- #!/xyz
- #!/123

I have the `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` included in the head of my page so the robots should visit those links using the following url and I am using prerender.io to serve up a page

- http://www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/abc
- http://www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/xyz
- http://www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/123

How will the robots behave when they crawl these pages? When they find new links on these pages what will the url's look like?

1. #!/abc1 => http://www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/abc#!/abc1
2. #!/abc2 => http://www.example.com/#!/abc/abc2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Google's full AJAX crawling specification: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

The robots will see the `#!` and transform them into `_escaped_fragment_` URLs, just like you mentioned. The `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` tag is only necessary for pages that don't have the `#!`, for example your home page or any HTML5 push state URLs. If the URL has a `#!`, Google will automatically ask for the `_escaped_fragment_` without checking for `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

If Google crawls `http://example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/abc` and finds a link on that page for `/#!/xyz`, it will make a separate request for `http://example.com?_escaped_fragment_=/xyz`.

So you should always have your URLs link to the `#!` URL, never to a `_escaped_fragment_` URL. Google will transform them on its own.